# FPDF performance worse on live server than localhost

Tags: mysql, performance, memory-leaks, lamp, fpdf

I have the following php script below that reads in about 2300 products with images etc from 20 categories using WAMP; the problem is that it take over 3 mins to create a pdf of 213 pages; based on the code is there a way of improving performance. I have already implemented these changes:

In php.ini

Find:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M
```

Change to:

```
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize = 750M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

And add this to C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.0.45\my.ini:

```
max_allowed_packet = 200M
```

this has stopped the outOfMemory exception I was getting & also when I run it on my VPS cloud server with the same settings it can up to over 10 minutes! any help please?(I know it's a big script file)(there is also a business rule of 12 products per page, 4 rows by 3)

```
<?php

// Database connection information
 require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');
 class catalogue {
var $pdf;
var $x;
var $y;
var $catName;
var $pageAdded;
var $headerAdded;
var $myFont = "futuram";
var $bgColor;
var $fontColor;
var $headerImage;
var $aTozArray;
var $pageAlreadyAdded;

// Constructor to generate a PDF of the catalogue
function catalogue() {
    global $pdf, $y;
    define ( 'EURO', chr ( 128 ) );
    $pdf = new FPDF ();

    $y = 0;
    $connect = mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxx' );
    if (! $connect)
        die ( 'Unable to connect to database' );
    $select = mysql_select_db ( 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' );
    if (! $select)
        die ( 'Unable to select database' );
    $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 );
    $pdf->SetMargins ( 0, 0, 0 );
    $this->addPage ();

    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futuram', '', 'futuram.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdbold', '', 'futurastdbold.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdboldoblique', '', 'futurastdboldoblique.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdbook', '', 'futurastdbook.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdbookoblique', '', 'futurastdbookoblique.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensed', '', 'futurastdcondensed.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedbold', '', 'futurastdcondensedbold.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedboldobl', '', 'futurastdcondensedboldobl.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedextrabd', '', 'futurastdcondensedextrabd.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedlight.php', '', 'futurastdcondensedlight.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedlightobl', '', 'futurastdcondensedlightobl.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedoblique', '', 'futurastdcondensedoblique.php' );     
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondensedboldobl', '', 'futurastdcondensedboldobl.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdcondextraboldobl', '', 'futurastdcondextraboldobl.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdheavy', '', 'futurastdheavy.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdheavyoblique', '', 'futurastdheavyoblique.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdlight', '', 'futurastdlight.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdlightoblique', '', 'futurastdlightoblique.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdmedium', '', 'futurastdmedium.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'futurastdmediumoblique', '', 'futurastdmediumoblique.php' );

    /*
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'Georgia', '', 'georgia.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'Georgia', 'I', 'georgiai.php' );
    $pdf->AddFont ( 'Georgia', 'B', 'georgiab.php' );
    */
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak ( true, 0 );


    // add the front pages
     $filename = 'http://localhost/images/Welcome_page_pic_fin-01.jpg';
     $pdf->Image ( $filename, 0, 0, 210, 297 );
     $this->addPage ();

    $this->getParent ();

    $pdf->Output ();
    // actually outputs the PDF. Can be automatically output to a file on
    // the server.
}


// Get parent categories
function getParent() {
    global $pdf, $x, $y, $page, $catName, $bgColor, $fontColor, $headerImage, $pageAlreadyAdded;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
    // This query returns all categories, but not sub categories

    $result = mysql_query ( $query );
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows ( $result );

    // For each category...
    for($i = 0; $i < $numrows; $i ++) {
        $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 40 );
        if ($page == 2) {
            $x = 15;
            $y = 20;

            $pdf->setX ( $x );
            $pdf->setY ( $y );
            // setY defines the y coordinate

            $page ++;
            // adds a page
        } else {


                //$this->addPage ();


        }

        $array = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
        // puts the actual category names into an $array

        $id = $array ['category_id'];
        $catName = $array ['category_name'];
        $image = $array ['category_icon'];

        $sql = "SELECT category_colour1, category_colour2, category_icon FROM categories WHERE category_id=$id";



        $coloursResult = mysql_query ( $sql );
        $coloursArray = mysql_fetch_array ( $coloursResult );

        $fontColor = $coloursArray ['category_colour1'];
        $bgColor = $coloursArray ['category_colour2'];

        $leaderImage = $coloursArray ['category_icon'];



        $pdf->setX ( 18.5 );
        // setX defines the x coordinate
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 );
        $pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 71, 53 );


        // $pdf->Cell ( 15, 20, $catName );
         if (@GetImageSize ( $image )) {
         //$filename = $leaderImage;
        // add in for test
         $filename = $image;
         } else {
         $filename = 'http://localhost/images/blank.jpg';
         }

         $pdf->Image ( $filename, 0, 0, 210, 297 );

        // creates a cell in the page. Notes:
        // http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm
        // If automatic page breaking is enabled and the cell goes beyond
        // the limit, a page break is done BEFORE outputting.

         $this->addPage ();

        $filename = 'http://localhost/images/blank.jpg';


        $this->getChildren ( $id, $catName);


        // calls the getChildren() function to gather the sub categories of
        // the given category being used
    }
}

// Get children
function getChildren($parent, $catName) {
    global $pdf, $y;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM shop_categories where parent_id = $parent ORDER BY category_id"; 


    $result = mysql_query ( $query );
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
    // $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // fix the case with $numrows = 0

    $catList = array ();

    while ( $array = mysql_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {

        array_push ( $catList, array (
                $array ['name'],
                $array ['category_id']

        ) );
    }


    $this->getProducts ( $catList,$catName );
}

// Get products in categories
function getProducts($catList,$catName) {
    global $pdf;
    $prodList = array ();
    $numSubCategories = count ( $catList );
    for($i = 0; $i < $numSubCategories; $i ++) {
        $catid = $catList [$i] [1];
        $query = "SELECT product_id,ProductName, WeightQuantity, PriceUnit, Euro, Pound, Code, Image FROM products where category_id = $catid order by product_id asc";
        $result = mysql_query ( $query );
        $numResults = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if($numResults > 0) {
        array_push ( $prodList, $result );
        }

    }   


    // If category is a parent send it back to getChildren
    if (count ( $prodList ) != 0) {
        $this->processPage ( $catList, $prodList,$catName );
    }
}
function processPage($catList, $prodList, $catName) {
    global $pdf, $catName, $page, $pageAdded, $myFont, $fontColor, $pageAlreadyAdded;
    $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 );
    $itemsPerRow = 3;
    $rowsPerPage = 4;
    $currentRow = 0;
    $numItems = 0;
    $totalRows = 0;
    $numberRowsUsed = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $prodList ); $i ++) {
        $items = mysql_num_rows ( $prodList [$i] );
        $totalRows += ceil ( $items / $itemsPerRow );
    }

    // changed this from $prodList[i] to $prodList
    for($i = 0; $i < count ( $prodList ); $i ++) {
        $subCatHeadName = $catList [$i] [0];


        if ($i > 0) {
            $numberOfitems = mysql_num_rows ( $prodList [$i - 1] );
            $numberRowsUsed += ( int ) ceil ( $numberOfitems / $itemsPerRow );
        }

        $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 28 );
        $fonts = explode ( ",", $fontColor );

        $pdf->SetTextColor ( 122, 114, 102 ); // grey

        $p = 0;
        $q = 0;
        $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetY ( 10 );
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->cMargin = 100;


        $p1 = 0;
        $q1 = 0;
        $pdf->SetX ( 0 );

        $numItems = mysql_num_rows ( $prodList [$i] ); // 5
        $numRows = ceil ( $numItems / $itemsPerRow ); // 2
        $remItems = $numItems % $itemsPerRow; // 2

        if ($numItems > 0) {
            for($j = 0; $j < $numRows; $j ++) {
                $this->processRow ( $itemsPerRow, $prodList [$i], $j, $currentRow,$subCatHeadName,$catName );
                $currentRow ++;
                if ($currentRow % $rowsPerPage == 0) {
                    $this->addPage ();
                    $pageAlreadyAdded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function processRow($numItems, $result, $rowNum, $currentRow,$subCatHeadName,$catName) {
    global $pdf;
    $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
    $pdf->SetY ( 20 );
    $this->header ();
    $this->footer ();
    if ($numItems > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $numItems; $i ++) {
            $this->processItem ( $result, $rowNum, $i, $currentRow,$subCatHeadName,$catName );
        }
    }
}
function processItem($result, $rowNum, $itemNum, $currentRow,$subCatHeadName, $catName) {
    global $pdf, $x, $y;
    $p1 = 0;
    $q1 = 0;
    $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
    $pdf->SetY ( $q1 + 10 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdmedium', '', 40 );
    $pdf->Cell ( 200, 16, $catName, 0, 5, 'C', true );

    $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
    $pdf->SetY ( $q1 + 25 );    
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdmedium', '', 10 );    
    $pdf->Cell ( 200, 8, $subCatHeadName, 0, 10, 'C', true );

    $a = 18.5;
    $b = 0;
    if ($currentRow % 4 == 0) {
        $rowNum = 0;
    } else if ($currentRow % 4 == 1) {
        $rowNum = 1;
    } else if ($currentRow % 4 == 2) {
        $rowNum = 2;
    } else if ($currentRow % 4 == 3) {
        $rowNum = 3;
    }
    $pdf->SetX ( $a );
    $pdf->SetY ( $b );
    $marginX = 0;
    $marginY = 30;
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 6 );
    $array = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
    $id = $array ['product_id'];
    $name = $array ['ProductName'];
    $price = $array ['PriceUnit'];
    $UKprice = $array ['Pound'];
    $Europrice = $array ['Euro'];
    $code = $array ['Code'];
    $weight = $array ['WeightQuantity'];
    $deltaX = 62.5;
    $deltaY = 64;

    $a = $marginX + ($itemNum * $deltaX);
    $b = $marginY + ($rowNum * $deltaY);

    $image = $array ['Image'];
    $imageName = ltrim ($image,':');
    if( $imageName == "" || $imageName == null) {
        $imageName = 'blank.jpg';
    }
    $filename = 'http://localhost/images/'.$imageName;

    // check if the image exists on the server; replaces it with a
    // placeholder otherwise

    if (@GetImageSize ( 'http://localhost/images/'.$imageName )) {
     $filename = 'http://localhost/images/'.$imageName;

     } else {
     $filename = 'http://localhost/images/blank.jpg';
     }


    if ($name != null) {
        $pdf->Image ( $filename, $a + 20, ($b), 55, 25 );
    }


    $pdf->setY ( $b + 30 );
    $pdf->setX ( $a + 5 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
    $pdf->setTextColor ( 122, 114, 102 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdheavy', '', 8.5 );
    $line1 = "";
    $line2 = "";
    if ($name != null) {
        if (strlen ( trim ( $name ) ) > 30) {
            $name = substr ( $name, 0, 30 );
            $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 );
            $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, trim ( $name ), 0, 0, 'C' );
        } else {
            $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 );
            $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, trim ( $name ), 0, 0, 'C' );
        }
    }
    $pdf->setY ( $b + 33 );
    $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
    //$pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdlightoblique', '', 7 );
    if ($name != null) {
        $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, 'Weight/Quantity '.$weight." ".$price, 0, 0, 'C' );
    }
    $pdf->setY ( $b + 36 );
    $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
    //$pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdlightoblique', '', 7 );
    if ($name != null) {
        $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, 'Price Unit <Euro> <Pound>', 0, 0, 'C' );
    }

    $pdf->setY ( $b + 39 );
    $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
//  $pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdbook', '', 7 );

    $UKprice = utf8_decode("£" . number_format($UKprice, 2));

    $Europrice = utf8_decode("EUR" . number_format($Europrice, 2));


    if ($name != null) {
        // $this->cell(10,10,iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", "£"). $money,0);
         $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, "PRICE: ".$Europrice ."  ".$UKprice, 0, 0, 'C' );
    }
    $pdf->setY ( $b + 42 );
    $pdf->setX ( $a + 35 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
    //$pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdbold', '', 8.5 );
    if ($code != null) {
        $pdf->Cell ( 10, 10, "CODE: ".trim($code), 0, 0, 'C' ); // the product code
                                                             // goes
                                                             // here, in
    }

    //$pdf->setTextColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdbold', '', 8.5 );
    // $y += 10; //move the y location down 10 (pixels...?)
    $pdf->setXY ( $a, $b + 32.5 ); // place the 'cursor' at these coordinates
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 0 );
    $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );

    $pdf->setY ( 0 );
    $pdf->setX ( 0 ); // price is placed where coordinate x=150
}

// Function to add a page to the PDF
function addPage() {
    global $pdf, $page, $y, $pageAdded;
    $pdf->AddPage ();
    // NOTE: this could have been $pdf->AddPage(P, A4) where P=portrait and
    // A4 is page size.
    // See http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm

    $pdf->Rect ( 0, 0, 250, 350, 'F' ); // The 'F' here means 'filled'. could
                                        // also be
                                        // 'D' for drawn border-only or DF for
                                        // drawn and
                                        // filled
    $y = 5;
    $pdf->setY ( $y );
    $page ++;
    $pageAdded = true;
}
function header() {
    global $pdf, $catName, $pageAdded, $headerAdded, $myFont, $fontColor, $bgColor, $headerImage;
    if ($pageAdded == true) {

        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 68.5 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 10 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetY ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 0, 0 ); // grey
        $pdf->Cell ( 77, 3, '', 0, 5, 'C', true );

        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $title = $catName;
        $image = $headerImage;
        $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 40 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetY ( 3 );

        $fonts = explode ( ",", $fontColor );
        $bg = explode ( ",", $bgColor );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // pure white
        $pdf->SetLineWidth ( 1 );
        $pdf->cMargin = 15;
        $pdf->Ln ( 10 );
        $headerAdded = true;
    }
    $pageAdded = false;
    $pdf->SetFont ( 'futuram', '', 14 );
    $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // white
}

function footer() {
    global $pdf, $headerAdded, $myFont, $fontColor, $bgColor;
    if ($headerAdded == true) {

        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetFont ( 'futurastdlight', '', 9 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetY ( - 18 );

        $fonts = explode ( ",", $fontColor );
        $bg = explode ( ",", $bgColor );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // grey
        $pdf->SetTextColor ( 122,114,102 ); // whitesmoke
    //  $pdf->Cell ( 0, 3, 'PRICES SUBJECT TO FLUCTUATION', 0, 1, 'C', true );
        $pdf->SetX ( 18.5 );

        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 4 );
        $pdf->SetY ( -0.05 );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 0, 0 ); // grey
        $pdf->Cell ( 28, -4,  $pdf->PageNo (), 0, 0, 'C', true );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // grey


        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 68.5 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 50 );
        $pdf->SetY ( - 3 );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 0, 0 ); // grey
        $pdf->Cell ( 77, 3, '', 0, 5, 'C', true );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // grey

        $pdf->SetLeftMargin ( 184 );
        $pdf->SetRightMargin ( 0 );
        $pdf->SetX ( 4 );
        $pdf->SetY ( -0.05 );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 0, 0 ); // grey
        $pdf->Cell ( 28, -4,  $pdf->PageNo (), 0, 0, 'C', true );
        $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 ); // grey
    }

    $headerAdded = false;
    $pdf->SetFont ( $myFont, '', 14 );
    $pdf->SetFillColor ( 255, 255, 255 );
}
```

}

$catalogue = new catalogue ();
?>

Comment: It's obvious that your VPS is way slower than your local computer. This question is the same as asking "What should I eat to outrun Usain Bolt. I ate potatoes yesterday. I don't run usually.".

Comment: but I implemented the same changes in the php.ini & the mySQL file as above; what's the difference then?

Comment: Different processor, hard disk, ram, network card and what not? Why do you think that same code can run fast or faster on slower computer? It's also some cloud based thing, how on earth can it run remotely close to real physical computer you have? You haven't even told us what's your local computer spec, but it's obvious that the server is way slower.

Comment: well okay, I get you now; any advice on the problem I have?